# how to open a folder without using Process.Start or Shell.Execute?

Tags: .net, directory, explorer

is there any way to open a windows explorer folder in .NET by some means other than "Process.Start()" or the WinAPI's ShellExecute function ?

Comment: There are probably countless other methods. But why would you not use `Process.Start`? If you tell us why you need an alternative, maybe we can suggest one of the countless possibilities.

Comment: Yeah, like you could create a shortcut to the folder and run it.  Or invoke a CMD prompt and run it that way too.  Why do you need to do it another way?

Comment: You can use Windows API

Comment: there is no business use here. i'm just curious. by teh way, in order to run the shortcut or invoke a CMD prompt you still have to resort to Process.Start.